# Jenkins won't start after an upgrade to 2.212

Tags: jenkins

On our Debian Jessie box, our Jenkins just got automatically upgraded from 2.210 to 2.211 and later to 2.212.  Around that same time, our JDK also got upgraded from openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 7u231-2.6.19-1~deb8u2 to 7u241-2.6.20-1~deb8u1.  Since then, Jenkins won't start and we get the following error in our logs:

```
2020-01-06 15:23:00.257+0000 [id=21]    INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: JVM is terminating. Shutting down Jetty
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
2020-01-06 15:23:01.835+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log#initialized: Logging initialized @432ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
2020-01-06 15:23:02.007+0000 [id=1] INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
2020-01-06 15:23:02.053+0000 [id=1] WARNING o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
2020-01-06 15:23:02.143+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-9.4.22.v20191022; built: 2019-10-22T13:37:13.455Z; git: b1e6b55512e008f7fbdf1cbea4ff8a6446d1073b; jvm 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-1~bpo8+1-b11
2020-01-06 15:23:02.401+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.util.TypeUtil#<clinit>: JVM Runtime does not support Modules
2020-01-06 15:23:02.419+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2020-01-06 15:23:02.469+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2020-01-06 15:23:02.470+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2020-01-06 15:23:02.473+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.server.session.HouseKeeper#startScavenging: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
2020-01-06 15:23:02.800+0000 [id=1] INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: /var/lib/jenkins found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2020-01-06 15:23:02.909+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@4bff7da0{Jenkins v2.212,/,file:///var/cache/jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/cache/jenkins/war}
2020-01-06 15:23:02.925+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStart: Started ServerConnector@531be3c5{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2020-01-06 15:23:02.925+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: Started @1522ms
2020-01-06 15:23:02.926+0000 [id=20]    INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Winstone Servlet Engine running: controlPort=disabled
2020-01-06 15:23:04.238+0000 [id=27]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started initialization
2020-01-06 15:23:04.901+0000 [id=26]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Listed all plugins
2020-01-06 15:23:07.057+0000 [id=28]    WARNING hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz#scout: Failed to scout io.jenkins.blueocean.service.embedded.analytics.BrowserAndOperatingSystemAnalyticsProperties
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.ensureOpen(PushbackInputStream.java:74)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:166)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.UnicodeReader.init(UnicodeReader.java:88)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.UnicodeReader.read(UnicodeReader.java:118)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.update(StreamReader.java:182)
Caused: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.update(StreamReader.java:198)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.<init>(StreamReader.java:62)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:411)
    at ua_parser.Parser.initialize(Parser.java:69)
    at ua_parser.Parser.<init>(Parser.java:44)
    at ua_parser.Parser.<init>(Parser.java:40)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.service.embedded.analytics.BrowserAndOperatingSystemAnalyticsProperties.<clinit>(BrowserAndOperatingSystemAnalyticsProperties.java:29)
Caused: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz.scout(ExtensionFinder.java:738)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:338)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:381)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:317)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.getComponents(ExtensionList.java:183)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$6.onInitMilestoneAttained(Jenkins.java:1172)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1.onAttained(InitReactorRunner.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorListener$Aggregator.lambda$onAttained$3(ReactorListener.java:102)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorListener$Aggregator.run(ReactorListener.java:109)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorListener$Aggregator.onAttained(ReactorListener.java:102)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$1.run(Reactor.java:177)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

As I am rather new to Jenkins sysadmin (I took the Jenkins system administration over from a colleague who left), I have no clue about how to solve this issue.  Any suggestions?

Comment: check status please `sudo service jenkins status`

Answer (score 0):

After some searching for the string "2.212" on https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/ I came across the following two issues that seemed related and also had to do with recent upgrades to version 2.212:

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-60641
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-60644

In the first issue comments, someone reported that version 2.211 worked for him, so I tried switching back to that version using

```
sudo apt-get install jenkins=2.211
```

and that solved my problem.